# Uniform convergence of a function sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The exercice is about this family of functions, 
A) check it is continuous on R
B) to which function (named f) this sequence is simply convergent? 
C) graph the function f sub k with special points and asymptotics. 
D) proof that the sup |fk-f| exist and calculate it, is there a point that reach this superior bound? Deduce if fk is uniformly convergent

Any help with questions c and d??

[image: function defined over R by]

Comment: I guess nobody likes function sequences!!